# Iteration on Objects key and Getting Values

Tags: reactjs

I have made a object in App component which has key values pairs, and the values itself are lists. I have passed this object to ListItem component. In ListItems component I want to iterate through all the keys and get all the values.

Comment: Can you please share the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is your first post (I'd like to point out that its best to share the code that you have tried so far, this way the community will be able to handle all your queries easily).

I am not sure how you've passed your object, but to iterate an object with all its keys and their array values, you can simply do this.

```
// iterate the object keys
for (let key in obj) {
  console.log(key);

  // iterate the array for that specific object key
  obj[key].forEach(val => console.log(val));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are succesfully receiving the value in your child component?

To iterate through the Object:

```
for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
    }
}
```

But, what is it that you want to do with the values?